# Chrome and Safari bug or background cover bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, border

I have this webpage where I have a picture a cover background. I notice that upon resizing the page the background moves a bit. Now that is not the problem and I guess that is also the function for the background cover property. However, in some percents 125% and 150% with Safari and Google Chrome, a 2px or 1px white border shows up on the left side of the screen. From top to bottom. I don't know the cause of this and I can't find the problem inside the style.css. So I wonder if any of you have the slightest idea if this is a bug or something related to me? 
The white border shows up with Google Chrome, Safari, Opera, but not Internet explorer :P

Comment: I haven't heard of this. Is it possible to see the page or could you put a fiddle together that replicates the issue?

Comment: It is somehow difficult to post a fiddle, but here is the picture at least: http://i49.tinypic.com/14b7uc0.png you can see the ridiculous white border on the left side there, and it goes all the way to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Come on some answers please, I would appreciate help :(

Comment: @MFCS - Have some patience. You just asked the question two hours ago on a Sunday U.S. time. No question here is any more or less urgent than any other, so we really frown on any attempts to game the system by trying to "bump" your questions.

Comment: Sorry :( I am inpatient.

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to see the source. The issue could be specifically related to your code rather than a browser bug.